# How to tell if a process started with CreateProcess is still running?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

If I've got a process created through `CreateProcess()`, how would I determine if it's still running? I know I need to use `pi.hProcess` but I don't know how, and google isn't really giving me meaningful hints.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
bool got_it=CreateProcess(NULL, CA2T(launchString.c_str()), NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any of the standard [wait functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069.aspx), like [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx), eg:

```
switch (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0))
{
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        // process has terminated...
        break;

    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        // process is still running...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the process's exit code with [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189.aspx), which will give the special `STILL_ACTIVE` value if the process is still running:

```
DWORD exit_code;
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exit_code);
if (exit_code == STILL_ACTIVE) {

}
```

Comment: What if the process returns `STILL_ACTIVE` (259) as its actual exit code?

Comment: @zett42: that is a possibility, and one that the documentation warns about: "***Important** The `GetExitCodeProcess` function returns a valid error code defined by the application only after the thread terminates. Therefore, an application should not use `STILL_ACTIVE` (259) as an error code. If a thread returns `STILL_ACTIVE` (259) as an error code, applications that test for this value could interpret it to mean that the thread is still running and continue to test for the completion of the thread after the thread has terminated, which could put the application into an infinite loop.*"

Comment: @Remy So it's not a general solution because it requires cooperation of the other process. Better use `WaitForSingleObject()` with 0 timeout instead.